# how to download files from gitweb

Tags: git

I want to download the source codes from 
the following link:

https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/b13c6becc892d9716d8645f16b5d03bdb0b34651:/src

but I'm not familiar with git,
how can I download all the files in this link?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to be familiar with git, try click in [snapshot](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/snapshot/b13c6becc892d9716d8645f16b5d03bdb0b34651.tar.gz)